# How to ensure code is executed in a specific order on inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, javafx, superclass

I have this super class extending `TableView`, that every table I want to make is supposed to inherit from.

This line of code needs to be executed for every class that inherits from the superclass and needs a `ContextMenu`:

```
// Sets the context menu for each specific row. This way no
// context menu will appear if we click on a row that is
// empty.
setRowFactory(r -> {
    TableRow<ObservableList<String>> row = new TableRow<ObservableList<String>>() {
        public void updateItem(ObservableList<String> item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (isEmpty()) {
                setContextMenu(null);
            } else {
                setContextMenu(contextMenu);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

The problem is that the `ContextMenu` needs to be instantiated before this code can be executed, hence I can't put in the constructor of the super class.

How do I ensure that every class inheriting from the super class does the following steps in this order if the table needs a `ContextMenu` (not always the case):

1. Instantiate the `ContextMenu` with `MenuItem` instances (I guess the `MenuItem` instances could be instantiated and added later on, theoretically).
2. Invoke the "setRowFactory" code above with the context menu instantiated in step 1.

I've had a few iterations on solving this issue, and still failed to come up with a satisfying solution. Maybe I'm missing something obvious.

**Edit:** Would be perfect if you could somehow disable the user from using the original`setContextMenu` method of `TableView`, to ensure that `ContextMenu is being added in the correct way. But I guess this isn't possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are simply trying to suppress showing the context menu on empty rows in the table. The simpler way to do this is

```
public class MyTableView<T> extends TableView<T> {

    public MyTableView() {
        setRowFactory(tv -> {
            TableRow<T> row = new TableRow<>();
            row.setOnContextMenuRequested(e -> {
                if (row.isEmpty()) {
                    e.consume();
                }
            }
            return row ;
        });
    }

    // ...
}
```

To answer the question you asked (ensuring you only (and always) call `setRowFactory` after a call to `setContextMenu`):

You can either do

```
public class MyTableView<T> extends TableView<T> {

    private final ContextMenu contextMenu ;

    public MyTableView(ContextMenu contextMenu) {
        this.contextMenu = contextMenu ;

        setRowFactory(r -> {
            TableRow<ObservableList<String>> row = new TableRow<ObservableList<String>>() {
                public void updateItem(ObservableList<String> item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (isEmpty()) {
                        setContextMenu(null);
                    } else {
                        setContextMenu(contextMenu);
                    }
                }
            };
        });

    }

    // ...
}
```

or

```
public class MyTableView<T> extends TableView<T> {

    private ContextMenu rowContextMenu ;

    public ContextMenu getRowContextMenu() {
        return rowContextMenu ;
    }

    public void setRowContextMenu(ContextMenu contextMenu) {
        this.rowContextMenu = contextMenu ;

        setRowFactory(r -> new TableRow<ObservableList<String>>() {
            public void updateItem(ObservableList<String> item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (isEmpty()) {
                    setContextMenu(null);
                } else {
                    setContextMenu(rowContextMenu);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // ...
}
```

or even

```
public class MyTableView<T> extends TableView<T> {

    public MyTableView() {
        contextMenuProperty().addListener((obs, oldContextMenu, newContextMenu) -> {
            if (newContextMenu == null) {
                setRowFactory(r -> new TableRow<>());
            } else 
                setRowFactory(r -> new TableRow<ObservableList<String>>() {
                    public void updateItem(ObservableList<String> item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if (isEmpty()) {
                            setContextMenu(null);
                        } else {
                            setContextMenu(newContextMenu);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me a couple of alternatives! The second one won't compile since `SetContextMenu` is a final method and can't be overriden, though. But overriding the super method was probably not the point of your example. Would be perfect if you could somehow disable the user from using `setContextMenu` from the `TableView`, to ensure that `ContextMenu is being added in the correct way. But I guess this isn't possible.

Comment: @JonatanStenbacka See updates. If all you are doing is suppressing the context menu on empty rows, you just need to consume the "context menu requested" event when it occurs on those rows. Fixed the issue with overriding final methods, and also repurposed the idea in the last option.

Comment: Quick note on the last example: I think you need to invoke `setContextMenu(null)` in the beginning, otherwise the `ContextMenu` will be the same for the entire table anyway. Also it doesn't compile since you need to return the row inside the `rowFactory`. I think I'll use that example anyhow, thank you for your help!